# Changing the project name

Tags: flutter

Is it possible changing the project name of a Flutter project? With project name I mean the name you provide when creating a flutter project `flutter create name`.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

That depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to change the name of the app which is displayed in the mobile phones menu together with the app icon, you have to change the `android:label` in the `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` (Code Sample 1) and the `CFBundleName` in the `ios/Runner/Info.plist` (Code Sample 2).

Last time I did this it took me ages to find out, why the name of the app was not changed in the list of currently running apps on Android. For that you also need to change the title of your MaterialApp (Code Sample 3).

For renaming it everywhere I would suggest to use search and replace in the project. If you do this, you have to choose a name without spaces or special characters. A project name 'new project' in the `pubspec.yaml` for example will break the build.

Code Sample 1:

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="New Name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

Code Sample 2:

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>New Name</string>
```

Code Sample 3:

```
return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'New Name'
  ...);
```

Comment: When I do this (and update corresponding `import "package:projectname/..."` statements), I still get errors stating that my dependency tree cannot be built. Is there anything else to rename? (I'm renaming the project folder as well).

Comment: In the `ios/Runner/Info.plist` i saw `CFBundleDisplayName` contain my app name too.. Should i change it too? Where is this string displayed?

Answer (score 33):

To change project name , you need to change it for all platforms .

You can use [**rename**](https://pub.dev/packages/rename) package to make it easy .
**Run this command inside your flutter project root**

```
flutter pub global run rename --appname "Application Name"
```

You can also specify the platform you want to apply the change

```
flutter pub global run rename --appname yourappname -t macOS  // support also ios and android
```

or

**Edit `AndroidManifest.xml` for Android and `info.plist` for iOS**

Do a `flutter clean` and restart your application if you have a problem.

Comment: Thanks! :)
It works, but the command to use is:
flutter pub [...]

not just
pub [...]

Comment: The command that worked for me was:
dart pub --suppress-analytics global run rename setAppName -v "Application Name"

Answer (score 10):

### You can let flutter do this for you:

Using Terminal:

```
cd /path/to/existing/flutter_project
flutter create --project-name newprojname --org com.yourorgdomain .
```

Next change the name on line 1 of **pubspec.yaml**

Trash all generated folders to remove all references of the old project name.

> NB - Some import statements will need to have their package references
> updated manually to the new name. Review the project structure (in
> your IDE) for any references to the old project name inside of IDE
> generated files.

Recreate the trashed generated files by using `flutter create .` (including the space and period at the end) from within the project folder.

Now run `flutter clean` then debug as normal

### Gotchas

You should expect that the project name still resides in all the generated folders for the various environments and in comments/strings. You can use a tool to search all files in the project or folder structure (e.g Cmd + Shift + F in Android Studio or ag {the_silver_searcher in Homebrew}) to find the old name and trash any generated folders including ios, windows, linux. After trashing the generated folders remember to re-create them by running `flutter create .`

Comment: perfect, this is the only solution that worked for me and it was very simple, the only thing i would add is to call `flutter.bat --no-color pub get` after changing the `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: also since i did allot of search replace of the old_project name, then i renamed the containing folder (`mv /path/to/existing/flutter_project /path/to/existing/flutter_new_project_name`) and if you have a firebase options file and googleservices file then replace them too with the ones obtained from firebase after recreating the mobile apps with the correct app name and the correct bundle id

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the project name, simply change it in all these files.

1. `build.gradle` (app)
2. `AndroidManifest.xml`
3. `MainActivity.java`

Rebuild your app and you should be good to go.

Comment: If you are attempting this in Android Studio, right-click on the package folder (i.e. com.example.oldname) and choose `Refactor > Rename...`.  The dialog will help you rename everything needed, and allow you to see what it is going to change.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad is it only change on Android right? what about ios

Comment: @BloodLoss Change BundleName in iOS

Answer (score 4):

To add to Rainer's answer, you may also have to change the com.example.myprojectname file under android/app/build.gradle

Also for the com.example.myprojectname, do not use underscores (ie:
com.example.my_project_name)

You may also have to find and replace the com.example.myproject name in the files project.pbxproj and MainActivity.java.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android Studio, from the Menu > Edit > Find > Replace in files > Enter old and new name...

[image]

Comment: I tried it for VScode, same place in the menu. I got error about CMake cache. Additionally I had to run `flutter clean` command. Then it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio, follow these steps:

1. Right-click your project in the Project window (Alt+1 to show).
2. Click Refactor > Rename.
3. Enter new name.

This will rename the project's name on all required places except in the test directory.

Comment: that only renamed the module (not the project / folder / app name ...)

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to rename your project: (For Editors that has search & replace across project feature)**

- Use VSCode's any other editor's search and replaceAll across entire project feature. But always turn on the `match cases` (for vscode: located on right side).

  - You have to do this two time as for the first you have to replace `com.orgname.currentname` with `com.orgname.newname` then
  - `currentname` with `newname`.
- Rename the folders inside `/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/orgname/currentname` to new `/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/orgname/newname`.
- If you're using only Java with flutter than just replace the `kotlin` with `java`.
- rename the `currentname.iml` of your root project folder to `newname.iml`

Answer (score 1):

1-`flutter clean`

2- Search and replace all `OLD_PROJECT_NAME` with `NEW_PROJECT_NAME`

3- Search for `OLD_PROJECT_NAME` in the project folder, and replace them with `NEW_PROJECT_NAME` one by one. Some of them are in the text files, make sure that you have changed them too.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+R then **Replace** for one by one replace
or **Replace All** for all at a time.
 Be cautious , if your project name is similar with other variable or class name then don't do that. Before doing that check twice.

Comment: Really dangerous. It should not be suggested as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the project name, simply change it in all these files.

```
build.gradle (app)
AndroidManifest.xml
MainActivity.java
```

Rebuild your app and you should be good to go.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).