# Different Project Name and App Display Name Impact on Deployment

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, dart

I want to change my App Display Name that shown in the phone but I am currently using Firebase as my backend and will be using another plugin where I need to register my project name and cannot change it.

My question is:
Is it possible to have issue in the future (i.e. on deployment phase to AppStore and PlayStore), if change my App Display Name according to the codes below **only** without changing anything else (i.e project name: `com.example.myprojectname`)?

Or should I refactor the whole project name as well and how do I do that if I already registered my project name to Firebase?

Android code:

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="New Name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

iOS code:

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>New Name</string>
```

Flutter code:

```
return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'New Name'
  ...);
```

Reference:
[Changing the project name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694153/changing-the-project-name)