# Rename project package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i has been create new flutter project with command `flutter create my-project`

can i rename the project from `my-project` to `my-new-app-name` without recreate new project...

like `import 'package:my-project/views/admin/v_panel.dart';`

to `import 'package:my-new-app-name/views/admin/v_panel.dart';`

i try use [pub.dev rename](https://pub.dev/packages/rename) but not work when i change the import code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter

Comment: May you check if the answers from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694153/changing-the-project-name) are useful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can rename your Project name without using Rename Package.Just change the name of your Folder...
But if you want to change the package name then you have 2 option ..

1. Use- rename: ^2.0.1 and  run this Command to your terminal

   pub global run rename --bundleId com.my-new-app-name
2. You have change it manually.. [How to change package name in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter)