# flutter pubspec.yaml deleted after updating

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, yaml

Hello experts I am facing very big issue I am made application in 2021 on flutter my application is still live on play store now I need update it, problem is that I updated my android studio flutter version 3.0. Now opening my old project which was made in 2021 after opening it my pubspec.yaml file is missing in the project, I don't no how to recover that file or repair it. They have a lot of dependencies  included there is pubspec.lock file available but not pubspec.yaml please please help me i am in big check screen shot below

[image: check now]

if i use flutter create command i am getting this errors

[image: flutter create command]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `pubspec.yaml` file on root directory or  open the bottom terminal and try `flutter create .` it will provide default structure. Now to get pub package, check the import section and add on `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: i am getting this "If run on a project that already exists, this will repair the project, recreating any files that are missing."

Comment: Are you able to processed with yes or just pressing enter

Comment: when i press enter

Comment: Can you include image what do you get after hitting enter

Comment: i edit my answer check image

Comment: Command will contain a dot('.') `flutter create .`

Comment: @iYeasin Sheikh ios signing is also required for this ?i am using mac  after using this command i am getting this erorrs "Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "Apple Development. "Hebrewappupdateproject" is not a valid Dart package name. "

Comment: The current issue is with package name, currently dart allow  snack_case project name.  try to [changing-the-project-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694153/changing-the-project-name)

Comment: yaml file create now i need add dependency manually?

Comment: yes if they are missing, also use null-safety version now

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup then paste the pubspec.yaml file from it. Else take a backup of the project. Run `flutter create .` in the root directory. It will create the pubspec file in the project. Click on configure dart and add the flutter path then run the project. It will throw errors for the packages used manually enter packages in pubspec or you can try `flutter pub add <packagename>`

Comment: i am getting this "If run on a project that already exists, this will repair the project, recreating any files that are missing

Comment: Yes confirm by entering yes and it will create it

Comment: there is no any confirmation message it show me another errors