# How to change flutter project name and import names at all?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I tried to use the "rename" package to change my project name, and of course, also imports that have the project name itself, but the package has only changed the project name. For example, my project name was A, and I updated it to B.

So, my project name was updated as B, but at the same time my project imports are still the same like:

```
import 'package:A...
```

So I also want to change import names to the new ones. How can I update my project name and also imports fully?

Note: I tried to change them manually, but I faced some problems when I want to implement firebase for example. So, I do not suggest changing manually, because the iOS bundle id and android package name should not be the same, I know.

Comment: > but I faced some problems
Can you describe what were the problems?

Comment: maybe you are looking for `export` or [melos](https://pub.dev/packages/melos)

Comment: Duplicate question, see this question for answers on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694153/changing-the-project-name

Comment: @Jet.B.Pope I want to change the existing project name, I do not want to create a new flutter project with the specific name

Comment: Yes, that is the exact question he is asking. Read further into the question and answers.

Comment: @LeoDog896 for firebase, I got this error: FirebaseCommandException: An error occurred on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command. So, I did research and I realized that it was because of package names, since I changed them manually

Comment: @Jet.B.Pope Right now I run the following command: pub global run rename --appname "Application Name", and it changed the project name. But imports are still the same

Comment: Yes, you will need to then go through and update those. Just do a global find/replace on it with the new ones you'll want

Comment: solved, look below. Thank you by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked everywhere, people do **not** mention generally the imports. So, here's the solution:

1- use the "rename" package first.

```
pub global run rename --bundleId com.onatcipli.networkUpp
    pub global run rename --appname "Network Upp"
```

2- Run the above command, and before this, change your **app name** and **bundleId**

3- go to **pubspec.yaml** file, and change the first line which is the "name" (this is for the imports)

4- **If you need**, run flutter clean

Comment: it's also tested for creating a flutter project in the Firebase.